# How to rephrase a sign text with a limited alphabet, but retain the meaning and humor?

Tags: language

I am creating a goofy sign for a pool using a vinyl letter set, which contains a limited alphabet of upper and lower case letters:

> AAABBBCCDDEEEFFGGHHIIIJJKKLLMMNNOOOPPQRRRSSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ
> aaabbccddeeeffgghhiiijjkklllmmnnnoooppqrrrsssttuuvvwwxxyyzz

I have run out of 'e'; I am flexible on capitalization and word usage, but I want to keep capitalization consistent within words and lines.

I want to retain the intent of the sign/phrase, and am open to rephrasing and synonyms. The lone P must be uppercase, as well as the OOL.  I currently have this, but cannot complete the final gag sentence.

> WELCOME
>
> to our OOL
>
> There is no P
>
> Please keep it that way

Non-English speakers: this is a silly request for pool users to not urinate while swimming.

Attempts to solve:

Replace "There is" with "Notice" I run out of 'o'.

Comment: This isn’t really a puzzle.

Comment: "It has no P". But even if you replace "there" you still need 4 lowercase **e** letters. This could be a [Lifehacks question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions) in which case I would say "buy another set of letters."

Comment: @Rubio The OP first posted this on [english.se] and they sent him here.

Comment: (@Randal'Thor) ... which unfortunately still doesn’t make it on-topic. Not every question is on topic somewhere on the SE network.

Comment: @Rubio I know, just saying.

Comment: I think this is a puzzle, right. Given this set of letters, how to make this following pun?

Comment: I love Stack Exchange: it's always here, ask a question, but no, not that one.

Comment: If you have scissors, it is simple to make an "e" out of "c" or "o" plus a straight segment from any unused letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that (on most such sets of letters I've seen), `p` and `d` are the same (just rotate 180°), my best attempt so far was:

> WELCOME to our OOL
>   Adding P is not requirep  *<= rotate 'p' to use as a 'd'*
>   Thanks

---

Additionally a meta-answer that may help you come up with more answers of your own more easily...

To experiment with different ideas, I created an Excel spreadsheet. In A1 I enter `AAABBBCCDDEEEFFGGHHIIIJJKKLLMMNNOOOPPQRRRSSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZaaabbccddeeeffgghhiiijjkklllmmnnnoooppqrrrsssttuuvvwwxxyyzz`, in B1, the text I want to try. In C1 `=FIND(LEFT(B1,1),A1)`.

In A2: `=LEFT(A1,C1-1)&MID(A1,C1+1,999)`, in B2 `=MID(B1,2,999)`, copy-paste C1 to C2, and copy-paste / replicate row 2 for as many rows as needed.

This way different text can be tried - any time you run out of a letter, you'll see `#VALUE!` in column C. For readability, you might want to give yourself a supply of vinyl spaces too!

This also showed that "keep it that way" is a problem phrase as the supply of letters only contains two `t`s.

Comment: You not only answered it with, in my opinion, a better answer phrase than those currently provided, but also supplied a workflow to identify other solutions.  That scores the win.

Comment: @JoshDM thanks! Also you can usually have `u` == `n` and `q` == `b` without much issue. For some specific letter sets it may be possible to "trim" some letters to create others too (craft knife / scissors) which could also expand your ool of available letters.

Answer (score 7):

Better to keep it short:

> WELCOME to our OOL.
>   Remember: no P.

Comment: Aesthetically, it's not great, but beggars can't be choosers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could you merge the request with the "no P" bit?

> WELCOME to our OOL
>
> No P please